# Does majority class treated as positive in Sklearn? Sklearn calculate False positive rate as False negative rate

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I'm working with classification with imbalanced data set using Sklearn. Sklearn has calculated the `false_positive_rate` and `true_positive_rate` wrong; when I want to calculate the AUC score, the result is different from what I have gotten from the confusion matrix.

From Sklearn I got the following confusion matrix:

```py
confusion = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
array([[  9100,   4320],
       [109007, 320068]], dtype=int64)
```

of course, I understand the output as:

```
+-----------------------------------+------------------------+
|        |       Predicted          |        Predicted       |
+-----------------------------------+------------------------+
| Actual | True positive = 9100     |  False-negative = 4320 |                       
| Actual | False-positive = 109007  |  True negative = 320068|
+--------+--------------------------+------------------------+
```

However, for FPR and TPR, I got the following result:

```py
false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred)
(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
(array([0.        , 0.3219076, 1.        ]),
 array([0.        , 0.7459488, 1.        ]))
```

The result is different from the `confusion_matrix`. According to my table, the FPR is actually FNR, and the TPR is actually TNR. Then I checked the [confusion matrix document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix), I found out that:

> Thus, in binary classification, the count of true negatives is C0,0, false negatives is C1,0, true positives is C1,1 and false positives is C0,1.

This means that the `confusion_matrix`, according to Sklearn, looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+---------------------------+
|        |       Predicted          |        Predicted          |
+-----------------------------------+---------------------------+
| Actual | True-Positive  = 320068  | False-Negative = 109007   |                       
| Actual | False-Positive = 4320    | True-Negative  = 9100     |
+--------+--------------------------+---------------------------+
```

According to the theory, for binary classification, the rare class is denoted as the positive class.

Why does Sklearn treat the majority class as positive?

Comment: What are your actual class labels?

Comment: The class label for the minority group was 0 and the majority group was 1.

Comment: I switched the class label for those two classes now, and got the right answer. It seems that Sklearn treat 1 as the positive class and 0 as the negative class.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the reason - unsurprisingly, 1 is treated as the positive class

Answer (score 1):

After some experiments, I found out that when `IsolationForest` from `sklearn` is used for *imbalanced data*, if you check `confusion_matrix`, It can be seen that `IsolationForest` treats the majority (Normal) class as a positive class whereas minor class should be the [positive class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56894608/10452700) in *Fraud/Outlier/Anomaly detection* tasks.

To overcome this challenge there are 2 solutions:

1. Interpret the confusion matrix results in vice versa. `FP` instead of `FN` and `TP` instead of `TN`.
2. If you want to pass the results correctly due to this bad treatment of IF for *imbalanced data* you can use the following trick:

Typically IF returns -1 for outliers and 1 for inliers so if you replace 1 with -1 and then -1 with 1 in the output from the `IsolationForest`, Then you could use the standard metric calculations correctly in this case.

```py
IF_model = IsolationForest(max_samples="auto",
                           random_state=11,
                           contamination = 0.1,
                           n_estimators=100,
                           n_jobs=-1)



IF_model.fit(X_train_sf, y_train_sf)
y_pred_test = IF_model.predict(X_test_sf)

counts = np.unique(y_pred_test, return_counts=True)
#(array([-1,  1]), array([44914,  4154]))

#replace 1 with -1 and then -1 with 1
if (counts[1][0] < counts[1][1] and counts[0][0] == -1) or (counts[1][0] > counts[1][1] and counts[0][0] == 1): y_pred_test = -y_pred_test
```

Considering confusion matrix [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html?highlight=confusion%20matrix#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix), and problem definition [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515654/how-can-we-introduce-an-anomaly-class-as-a-positive-class-to-sklearn-isolationfo), above trick should work and right form of confusion matrix for Fraud/Outlier/Anomaly detection or Binary classifiers based on litertures [Ref.1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11280-018-0582-1/figures/4), [Ref.2](https://scoredata.com/how-to-detect-fake-online-reviews-using-machine-learning-2/), [Ref.3](https://www.knime.com/blog/from-modeling-to-scoring-confusion-matrix-and-class-statistics) is as follows:

```
+----------------------------+---------------+--------------+
|                            |  Predicted    |  Predicted   |
+----------------------------+---------------+--------------+
| Actual (Positive class)[1] |      TP       |      FN      |                       
| Actual (Negative class)[-1]|      FP       |      TN      |
+----------------------------+---------------+--------------+
```

```py
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test_sf, y_pred_test).ravel()
print("TN: ",tn,"\nFP: ", fp,"\nFN: " ,fn,"\nTP: ", tp)
print("Number of positive class instances: ",tp+fn,"\nNumber of negative class instances: ", tn+fp)
```

check the evaluation:

```py
print(classification_report(y_test_sf, y_pred_test, target_names=["Anomaly", "Normal"]))
```

Comment: Hello @Mario, so is this only the case when we use the ```confusion_matrix``` or we should tell the Isolution Forest learner upon training which class has which label ?

Comment: @Perl Basically IF is an **un**supervised model (Nevertheless it can be used with supervised setup for final model evaluation). `confusion_matrix` from Sklearn *might* throw this problem/ bad treatment.