# What is the positive class in anomaly detection?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anomaly-detection

Currently, I try to implement an anomaly detection algorithm with scikit-learn in python. I relabeled the dataset to Inliers (Normal instances) are labelled `1`, while outliers (Anomaly instances) are labelled `-1` ([Reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html))

For the calculation of accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score and f1_score I get different values when I set `pos_label=1` or `pos_label=-1`.

So what is the label of the positive class in the context of anomaly detection: `1` or `-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interested in finding what samples are outliers. Then, positive class is the outliers. 
 
Note: Generally, you should try to improve the recall rather than the precision score, because you need to reduce false negatives (predict that an outlier is an inlier)